# Can I provide a boolean value in layout in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that we can provide some string value in layout like this:

```
<%= provide(:title, "HOME") %>
```

but can I provide some boolean value? I tried to provide like this:

```
<%= provide(:headless, true) %>
```

but I get `''` instead of `true`.

Comment: Did my answer below helped you?

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka env variable is not in my consideration

Comment: @variable is an instance variable not environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your intentions.

If you want to use boolean value in your layout:

```
<% if yourboolean %>
  do something
<% end%>
```

you can declare instance variable in your template. Not the most clean solution but I occasionally use it for small hacks.

in template:

```
<% @headless = true %>
```

so in your layout you can now:

```
<% if @headles %>
  do headless stuff 
<% end %>
```

if @headless is not defined anywhere it will return nil.